# Apply bootstrap multiselect for dropdownlistfor

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create dropdown list as shown in the below jsfiddle example.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example-getting-started').multiselect();
    });

 <select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
```

[image]

This is working fine As shown in above screenshot. But I want to apply this same scenario to @Html.Dropdownlist for element. But it seems I am getting unexpected issues such as select only one value.  As shown in below screenshot.

```
@Html.DropDownList(m => m.Detail, new SelectList(ViewBag.detailList, "Value", "Text"), new { id = "det" })

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#det').multiselect();
});
```

Maybe we can't apply this plugin for dropdownlistfor elements. Any help is appreciate. Thanks

**Updated**: This issue occurred due to the multiple attribute. I added it to dropdownlistfor as shown below and it works fine.

```
 @Html.DropDownListfor(m => m.Detail, new SelectList(ViewBag.detailList, "Value", "Text"), new { id = "det", multiple ="multiple" })
```

Comment: Can you provide your code ?

Comment: @Minar updated the question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.found the issue.I updated the question

Answer (score 1):

cant see the code but i believe you'r using radio buttons in the second image use checkbox like the first image and it will get solved

or please add you'r code to the question,thank you

Comment: Updated the question. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply.found the issue.I updated the question